# Laravel Data Deletion

Tags: laravel

How can I prevent data deletion if the data of one data-table is used in another data-table as foreign key in Laravel?
This is a **controller** from where I have to delete data.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Theme;

class ThemeController extends Controller
{

    public function destroy($id)

        Theme::destroy($id);
        return redirect()->route('theme.index')->withFlashSuccess('Theme profile is deleted successfully.');
    }
}
```

How can I apply a condition to stop the deletion the data in this controller, if this controller data is used in another controller?

Comment: you can add relation and check if the relation colection is notEmpty

Comment: can you share the table structure that holds the relation data

Comment: no. i m not using migration method in this project

Comment: ok just share the mysql table structure that needs to be checked before deleting the data that is Theme

Comment: this is table structure where theme is been used as a foreign key
idPrimary int(11) general_agreement_id varchar(225)   theme_id   varchar(225)

Comment: share the table name too

Comment: table name general_agreement_theme

Comment: can you check now

Comment: you are always welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and Replace With  Your Current Function

```
  public function destroy($id)
{
    $foriegnKeyCheck = DB::table('general_agreement_theme ')
            ->where('theme_id' ,$id)->get();

    if($foriegnKeyCheck->isEmpty())
    {
        Theme::destroy($id);
        return redirect()->route('theme.index')->withFlashSuccess('Theme profile is deleted successfully.');
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('theme.index')->withFlashSuccess('Theme profile is deleted successfully.');
    }

}
```

And Don't Forget to import

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

At the top of the controller

Hope it helps

if you are facing any issue kindly comment below

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure your relationships are correct:

**relationship from Theme to ThemeLess (in your Theme model) make sure you have a foreign key `theme_id` this is what laravel will look for by default**

```
public function ThemeLess() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ThemeLess');
}
```

This will only delete the theme if the count is equal to or less than 0

**Updated:** you can also improve your delete function, if you are going to use this make sure your route looks like this: `Route::delete('/theme/{theme}', 'ThemeController@destroy')`

```
public function destroy(Theme $theme)
{
   if (count($theme-> themeLess) <= 0) {
        $theme->delete();
        return redirect('/your/route');
   }else{ 
        return back()->withErrors('failed to delete'); 
   }
}
```

Both ways should solve your problem just make sure your relationship is correct.

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GeneralTheme extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'general_agreement_theme';

    protected $fillable = ['id','theme_id','general_agreement_id'];

    public function theme()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ThemeLess');
    }
}
this is the relation model

Comment: in Theme i have belongs to relationship

Comment: @SijanShrestha updated answer should work given that your relationship is correct and your foreign key is correct.